# Get index of entry in database without getting the other results

Tags: php, mysql

Let's jump right into my problem and imagine that we have this simple table

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `score` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `score`)
VALUES
    (1, 10),
    (2, 15),
    (3, 6),
    (4, 17);
```

What I want to do is the following. I want to sort by score and then, get the rank of the field with the ID 3

Since the entry with the ID 3 has the lowest score it would be rank 4.

I have this query, to get the ranks sorted by score

`SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rank, id, score from test t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r ORDER BY score DESC;`

The result is the following

```
rank  ||  id  ||  score

  1       4       17
  2       2       15
  3       1       10
  4       3       6
```

However, what I want to achieve is to get the rank instantly. Without having the ranks and results of the other values. I can't just add a `WHERE CLAUSE` with the condition that the `ID` should be 3, because If I do so the rank is always 1 because the query only matches one entry in the database.

How would I get the rank directly without iterating somehow over the result?

Comment: Have you tried using 'having id=3' at the end of your query?

Comment: Hi, I just did, but the problem is the same as if I would be using where. This is the edited query: `select @rownum:=@rownum+1 rank, id, score from test t, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r HAVING id =3 order by score DESC ;` Still the rank is `1` instead of 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just count how many are better than the id you want the rank of?

For example for id 3:

```
SELECT count(*)+1 FROM test where score > (SELECT score from test WHERE id = 3))
```

Just change the id at the end of the subquery to get the rank of another id

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the input. I didn't chose this variant because I am scared that the query will take some time if I have over 10.000 entries in the database. Also, there would be some WHERE clauses in addition to the current query.

Would the query still be performant enough?

Comment: i just run some tests with over 100.000 entries - it took between 0.028 and 0.050 seconds - and this without having a proper index on score. in my opinion the performance will mostly depend on the WHERE clauses

Answer (score 1):

Add a index to score column and use below query-

```
select count(*) from test a join test b on a.score > b.score where a.id =3
```